# how to get lowest unique bid in SQL

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

what do i add to this query to get the lowest unique bid?

```
SELECT auction.title, auction.auction_id, bid.name, bid.price
FROM auction INNER JOIN
     bid
     ON auction.auction_id = bid.auction_id
```

Comment: Which dbms do you use?

Comment: i use mariaDB :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `GROUP BY` with `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT
    b.name,
    b.price
FROM auction a
INNER JOIN bid b
    ON a.auction_id = b.auction_id
WHERE
    a.name = 'some name goes here'
GROUP BY
    b.name,
    b.price
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY
    b.price
LIMIT 1;
```

The above query aggregates by bid, and then retains only those bids which appear once (`HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`).  Then, it orders ascending by the bid price, and retains only a single row, that row being the lowest price.

Comment: I'm assuming there are multiple auctions with multiple bids and the OP is trying to get the minimum bid per auction... I could be mistaken though.

Comment: That can't be the full requirement, because the OP mentions _unique_ bids.  I will wait for feedback from the OP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Curious; wouldn't `MIN()` (also) work?

Comment: No, it wouldn't.  At least it wouldn't be the same query, because then we wouldn't have the name of the bid as well.

Comment: Great this works, now where would I need to add a WHERE statement to select only from a specifik a.name?

Comment: I changed it to this

Comment: SELECT
    b.name,
    b.price,
    a.title
FROM auction a
INNER JOIN bid b
    ON a.auction_id = b.auction_id
GROUP BY
    b.name,
    b.price,
    a.title
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY
    b.price
LIMIT 1 WHERE a.name = "Weekend Parijs"

but the WHERE doesn't work, where do i need to add it?